# Drupal Commerce Rules & Custom Actions

Tags: commerce, rules, actions

When the checkout process is complete I'd like to record the SKU and the user ID in a separate table in my database.

Is the best approach to use the Rules module, using the 'Completing the checkout process' event and writing a custom action?

If so, how would I be best going about this?

Advice on how best to achieve the above would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any modules that enable you to write db records in rules actions.

I guess you could write a custom rules action to write to your custom table and grab all the data in rules but it's just as easy to do something like below using  [hook_commerce_checkout_complete](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!checkout!commerce_checkout.api.php/function/hook_commerce_checkout_complete/7):

*The trickiest part is obtaining the SKU*

```
<?php
  function hook_commerce_checkout_complete($order) {
    $ow = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);

    foreach ($ow->commerce_line_items as $line_item) {
     $sku = $line_item->commerce_product->sku->value();

     $record = array(
      'uid' => $uid,
      'order_id' => $order->order_id,
      'order_numer' => $order->order_number,
      'sku' => $sku,
     );
     drupal_write_record('my_custom_table', $record);
    }
  }
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give this a go and get back to you. Looks like the sort of things I'm searching for.